# How to get the ARN of an AWS-CDK delivery stream construct

Tags: aws-cdk, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I am creating a [CfnDeliveryStream](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-kinesisfirehose.CfnDeliveryStream.html) in CDK and I would like to use the ARN later in an IAM role. I found the attribute [attrArn](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-kinesisfirehose.CfnDeliveryStream.html#attrarn), but it is undocumented. My question is: how do I access the ARN of a delivery stream (similar to what is available in [S3 constructs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-s3.Bucket.html#bucketarn)).

Thanks,
Benni

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the following syntax -

```js
const resourceARN = cdk.Fn.getAtt(%ID_YOU_WANT_TO_GET%, "Arn").toString();
```

**Usage:**

```js
    const lambdaFunction = new sam.CfnFunction(scope, "myLambdaID", {
      functionName: name,
      runtime: 'nodejs10.x',
      codeUri: {
        bucket: lambdaAssest.s3BucketName,
        key: lambdaAssest.s3ObjectKey
      },
      handler: handler,
      timeout: timeout,
      autoPublishAlias : `current`
    });

    const lambdaARN = cdk.Fn.getAtt( lambdaFunction.logicalId, "Arn").toString();
```

To verify the ARN, use `cdk.CfnOutput` -

```js
new cdk.CfnOutput(scope, `output-arn`, { value: lambdaARN });
```

Comment: thanks for the prompt answer. I am getting the following error: _instance of Fn::GetAtt references undefined resource_ Do you have any idea what that could be?

Comment: using lambdaFunction.logicalId instead of "myLambdaID" worked for me.

Comment: Glad i could help :)